# Erro ao chamar serviço REST

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Ontem de boa, meu serviço funcionou, exceto para campos float, mas comentando essa parte até ter uma solução, eu estava testando e funcionando, em realidade uma APP Android para consumir esse serviço. Hoje fui colocar no ar e me deu esse problema. Tentei hospedar em meu site e deu também. Esse é o erro explodido no browser:

> Ocorreu um erro.  O tipo
>   'ObjectContent`1' não pôde serializar o corpo da resposta para o tipo
>   de conteúdo 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'. </ExceptionMessage>
>   <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
>   <StackTrace/> <InnerException> <Message>Ocorreu um erro.</Message>
>   <ExceptionMessage> O tipo
>   '<>f__AnonymousType4`7[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Single]'
>   não pode ser serializado. Considere marcá-lo com o atributo
>   DataContractAttribute e marcar todos os membros que deseja serializar
>   com o atributo DataMemberAttribute. Se o tipo for uma coleção,
>   considere marcá-lo com CollectionDataContractAttribute. Consulte a
>   documentação do Microsoft .NET Framework para obter outros tipos
>   suportados.  
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException
>     em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String
>   message, Type type) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle
>   typeHandle, Type type) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type
>   objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle
>   declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType,
>   Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) em
>   WriteArrayOfanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract ) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean
>   verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type
>   declaredType) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) em
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter
>   writer, Object graph) em
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) em
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior
>   onde a exceção foi gerada --- em
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) em
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) em
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()

Abaixo o meu serviço:

```
public class Autoriza
    {
        InetContext contexto = new InetContext();
        Liberacao liberacao = new Liberacao();
        public IEnumerable<object> getAutoriza()
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                .Join(contexto.ItensLibs, lib => lib.IdOrcamento, itens => itens.IdOrcamento, (lib, itens) => new { lib, itens })
                .Where(a => a.lib.IdOrcamento == a.itens.IdOrcamento)
                .Select(libera => new
                {
                    libera.lib.TipoVenda,
                    //libera.lib.Vencimento,
                    //libera.lib.Juros,
                    //libera.lib.Entrada,
                    //libera.lib.Acrescimo,
                    //libera.lib.Desconto,
                    libera.lib.Mensagem,
                    //libera.lib.DataLib,
                    libera.lib.Vendedor,
                    libera.lib.Cliente,
                    libera.lib.Filial,
                    libera.itens.Produto,
                    //libera.itens.Qtde,
                    //libera.itens.Unitario,
                    //libera.itens.Custo,
                    //libera.itens.CustoDiario,
                    libera.itens.UltCondicao
                    //libera.itens.Total
                }).ToList();

            return lista;
        }
```

Minha controller:

```
public class AutorizaController : ApiController
    {
        Autoriza autoriza = new Autoriza();

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<object> getLiberacao()
        {
            return autoriza.getAutoriza().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Não sei o que pode estar acontecendo. No meu site está dando esse erro:

> Falha de logon do usuário 'REDEHOST\meudomínio.co_web'

Minhas tentativas: Veja que o erro sugere colocar alguns atributos na classe e fiz isso e mesmo assim, não funcionou. O que eu não entendo é que ontem, sem que eu mexesse em alguma coisa, funcionou exceto pelos float.

Esse erro também está no site e deu comigo, mas porque o Sql Server estava fora:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

Falei com o provedor(REDEHOST) sobre isso, mas não obtive resposta, como sempre da redehost.

**EDIT1**
Minha classe de entidade:

```
[Table("LIBERACAO")]
    public class Liberacao
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("ID_LIBERACAO")]
        public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_LIBERACAO")]
        public byte FlagLiberacao { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_ORCAMENTO")]
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_VENDEDOR")]
        public int IdVendedor { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDEDOR")]
        public string Vendedor { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_FILIAL")]
        public int IdFilial { get; set; }
        [Column("FILIAL")]
        public string Filial { get; set; }
        [Column("DATALIB")]
        public float DataLib { get; set; }
        [Column("HORALIB")]
        public float HoraLib { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_CLIENTE")]
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        [Column("CLIENTE")]
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        [Column("TIPO_VENDA")]
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS")]
        public float Juros { get; set; }
        [Column("DESCONTO")]
        public float Desconto { get; set; }
        [Column("VENCIMENTO")]
        public float Vencimento { get; set; }
        [Column("ACRESCIMO")]
        public float Acrescimo { get; set; }
        [Column("ENTRADA")]
        public float Entrada { get; set; }
        [Column("PRAZO")]
        public float Prazo { get; set; }
        [Column("TOTAL_LIQUIDO")]
        public float TotalLiquido { get; set; }
        [Column("MIN_TOTAL")]
        public float MinTotal { get; set; }
        [Column("USUARIO")]
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        [Column("CUSTODIARIO")]
        public Decimal CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [Column("MAX_COMI")]
        public Decimal MaxComi { get; set; }
        [Column("VALOR_COMI")]
        public Decimal ValorComi { get; set; }
        [Column("NOVA_COMI")]
        public Decimal NovaComi { get; set; }
        [Column("MENSSAGEM")]
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
        [Column("Menssagem_RET")]
        public string MensagemRet { get; set; }
        [Column("DataRetorno")]
        public double DataRetorno { get; set; }
        [Column("HoraRetorno")]
        public double HoraRetorno { get; set; }
        [Column("TempoProcesso")]
        public double TempoPrecesso { get; set; }
        [Column("Tipo")]
        public int Tipo { get; set; }
        [Column("PROGRAMA")]
        public string Programa { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PC")]
        public string NomePc { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PROCEDURE")]
        public string NomeProcedure { get; set; }
        [Column("Perc_Juros_Total")]
        public decimal PercJurosTotal { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_CULTURAVENCIDA")]
        public byte FlagCulturaVencida { get; set; }
        [Column("CULTURA")]
        public string Cultura { get; set; }
        [Column("CULTURA_VCTO")]
        public int CulturaVcto { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_PRORROGADO")]
        public byte FlagProrrogado { get; set; }
        [Column("VALOR_PRORROGADO")]
        public double ValorProrrogado { get; set; }
        [Column("DIAS_ATRASO")]
        public int DiasAtrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_VENDEDOR2")]
        public int IdVendedor2 { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDEDOR2")]
        public string Vendedor2 { get; set; }
        [Column("COMISSAO_VEND2")]
        public double ComissaoVend2 { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_COTACAO")]
        public byte FlagCotacao { get; set; }
        [Column("TipoVenda")]
        public string TipoVenda1 { get; set; }
        [Column("Flag_Receber_Atrasado")]
        public byte FlagReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
        [Column("Autorizou_Receber_Atrasado")]
        public string AutorizouReceberAtrazado { get; set; }

    }

[Table("ITENSLIB")]
    public class ItensLib
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("ID_ITENSLIB")]
        public int IdItensLib { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_ORCAMENTO")]
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_PRODUTO")]        
        public int IdProduto { get; set; }
        [Column("PRODUTO")]
        public string Produto { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE")]
        public float Qtde { get; set; }
        [Column("UNITARIO")]
        public float Unitario { get; set; }
        [Column("CUSTO")]
        public float Custo { get; set; }
        [Column("MINIMO")]
        public float Minimo { get; set; }
        [Column("TOTAL")]
        public float Total { get; set; }
        [Column("CUSTODIARIO")]
        public Double CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [Column("FABRICANTE")]
        public string Fabricante { get; set; }
        [Column("ULT_CONDICAO")]
        public Double UltCondicao { get; set; }
        [Column("PROGRAMA")]
        public string Programa { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PC")]
        public string NomePc { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PROCEDURE")]
        public string NomeProcedure { get; set; }
        [Column("Flag_Vencido")]
        public byte FlagVencido { get; set; }
        [Column("TipoVenda")]
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_VISTA")]
        public float VendaVista { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_AVISTA")]
        public float MargemAvista { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_NEG_AVISTA")]
        public float QtdNegAvista { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_PRAZO")]
        public float VendaPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("PM_PRAZO")]
        public float PmPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_PRAZO")]
        public float MargemPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS_PRAZO")]
        public float JurosPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_PRAZO")]
        public float QtdePrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_VISTA_ANT")]
        public float VendaVistaAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_AVISTA_ANT")]
        public float MargemAvistaAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_NEG_AVISTA_ANT")]
        public float QtdeNegAvistaAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float VendaPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("PM_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float PmPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float MargemPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float JurosPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float QtdePrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_VISTA_ANT1")]
        public float VendaVistaAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_AVISTA_ANT1")]
        public float MargemAvistaAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_NEG_AVISTA_ANT1")]
        public float QtdeNegAvistaAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float VendaPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("PM_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float PmPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float MargemPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float JurosPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float QtdePrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Você consegue consumir o serviço de outra aplicação? Por exemplo usando o **Postman**? Verificou se não tem problema de autenticação para o usuário *co_web*, por exemplo, senha expirada?

Comment: @RicardoPontual, ontem estava testando pelo Postman e estava ok, sem problemas. Hoje já não consegui. Tentei um serviço que pegeui num tutorial do Macoretti e tambám não funcionou, mas pode ser que o serviço estivesse fora, pensei. O que não entendemo é o co_web. Não sei o que é isso.

Comment: Pensei nisso por causa do erro que você comentou "*Falha de logon do usuário 'REDEHOST\meudomínio.co_web'*"

Comment: @RicardoPontual, acho que meu serviço está bugado e pela resposta do Gabriel, pode ser que tem a ver, pois subi outro serviço que eu fiz pro meu site e está ok, inclusive sendo consumido pelo meu App Android que estou fazendo, então acho que é mesmo o serviço. No mais, agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Não é interessante você trabalhar com entidades (ou `object` no seu caso) do banco de dados direto na sua Controller porque os seus dados pode vim em uma formatação que o seu serializador pode não entender ou formatar errado. Minha recomendação para evitar esses erros de formatação de float que você esta tendo é utilizar uma classe Model com mapeamento e formatar os seus dados para facilitar essa serialização.

Por exemplo, eu poderia utilizar o AutoMapper para fazer essa formatação:

```
CreateMap<Liberacao, LiberacaoModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Juros, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Juros.ToString("C3")));
```

No meu exemplo, agora eu estou garantindo que meu Juros sempre terá três casas decimais e corretamente formatado para não quebrar a minha serialização.

O que eu entendi do seu código e do erro, o seu serializador não esta entendo esse .Join() ai quando você retorna eles como um `object`, é difícil saber sem as duas entidades que você faz o join para analisar.

Comment: Ok, eu acho que o Gabriel Coletta está certo sim. Eu fiz um outro serviço e funcionou corretamente. Acho que você matou, provavelmente uma outra situação. Estou postando as duas entidades(minhas classes de domínio), como você comentou.

Comment: Notei que você esta usando a classe Double ao invés do tipo double, e de acordo com uma fração do stack do erro: [System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Single]' não pode ser serializado. Ele não esta conseguindo serializar ele.

Comment: Eu fiz isso apenas para teste, pois com float ou double estava dando erro e consegui apenas com um atributo funcionar, mas os demais também continuaram com o erro

Comment: Estou refazendo o projeto todo, pois estava bem no começo e consegui, agora preciso criar o serviço que vai entregar e o método na model que eu estava usando, passando um objeto, terei que refazer, seguindo seu comentário, mas nunca usei o AutoMapper. Preciso ler alguma coisa dele

Comment: Existe várias opções parecidas, até mesmo a possibilidade de você mesmo fazer um método que faça esse mapeamento. Eu recomendei o AutoMapper pois é o que eu possui mais experiência.